# SoapUI Load Testing - Define a Curve to Test On

Tags: load-testing, soapui

I am trying to run a test with 11 steps, and I want to define a curve of how frequently tests will be sent. That is, I want to start off with one request per second, then graduate that until I hit a maximum of 15 requests per second, sustain that for a period of time (say, 10 minutes), and then end the test. Is this possible or is the only way to start at that number of requests immediately?

Answer (score 0):

All possible load strategies are listed under [Simulating different types of Load](https://www.soapui.org/docs/load-testing/simulating-different-types-of-load/) SoapUI documentation page and no one really fits your needs.

So maybe it worth considering [converting your SoapUI test to JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-convert-soapui-xml-jmeter-jmx), this way you will be able to use [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/) and enjoy more comprehensive test results in form of the [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)